# Is pickleball becoming more popular?

Tags: pickleball

Everywhere I look, I hear more and more about pickleball. I see many local public tennis courts converting some of their courts to accommodate pickleball. [Tom Brady, LeBron James, and Kevin Durant](https://www.cnbc.com/2022/10/20/kevin-durant-is-latest-athlete-to-buy-into-major-league-pickleball.html) are investing in the sport and and Major League Pickleball. Is there any evidence that pickleball is actually picking up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, according to [USA Pickleball](https://usapickleball.org/news/fastest-growing-sport/):

[image: USA Pickleball]